# Will my necrotic-damage-heavy PC be too weak in Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, warlock, damage-types, curse-of-strahd

I'm preparing a character for Curse of Strahd, which I have never played before. This character uses a lot of necrotic damage. I don't mind if this character is not the absolute best choice for this campaign, but on the other hand I don't want to be too underpowered.

Keeping spoilers to a minimum, is relying on necrotic damage a poor choice for this campaign, or is it just a minor issue?

Specifically, I'm looking to play a Hexblade Warlock with Hex and Arms of Hadar - both necrotic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keeping spoilers to a minimum: there are some enemies in Curse of Strahd with resistance or immunity to necrotic damage. However it’s not most of the enemies and you should do fine in this respect. They’re primarily the types of creatures (like vampires!) where everyone is expected to go a little outside their standard “I hit it with my basic attack again” approach.

Thematically, necrotic damage is perfectly at home in this adventure. Your DM will probably have fun with this PC theme choice.